# Show least generating set of $S_n$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

Let $n ≥ 2$ and define $V =$ {  $x , x+1: 1 ≤ x < n$}.

Show $V$ generates $S_n$ and that it is a minimal generating set for $S_n$.

I'm having a hard time with this. But I do have some ideas on how I can prove this:

First I need to show $V$ generate $S_n$.
To do this I was thinking about trying to show that this set generates another set $W$, that is known to generate $S_n$. So trying to show $V$ generates $W =$ {$(1,2) , (1,2,...,n)$}, since I already know that $W$ generates $S_n$ from class. I'm a bit stuck on actually showing this, and I was also wondering if there's a better way to maybe prove $V$ generates $S_n$?

Then, I to show $V$ is a minimal generating set for $S_n$, I was thinking about showing that for any fixed $y$ with $1≤y<n$, the set $M =$ $V$\ {$y,y+1 $} does not generate $S_n$. I'm a bit stuck on actually showing this though.

Comment: Use `$\{ x\}$` for $\{ x\}$.

Comment: In the first line $V$ is defined incorrectly. Your plan to use $(1,2,...,n)$ is the best possible.

Comment: Do you mean "irredundant" generating set or "minimal size"?

Comment: @Shaun thanks for the format!

Comment: "Least" implies minimum: that is, smallest. As the text you quote notes, you are actually finding *minimal* generating sets: sets such that no strictly smaller set generates. And your $V$ should presumably be $V=\{(x,x_1)\mid 1\leq x\lt n\}$ (transpositions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$V=\{(i,i+1), i=1,...,n-1\}$. Then let  $n\ge 3$, we have $(1,2,...,n)=(n-1,n)\cdot ...\cdot (2,3)\cdot (1,2)$ (composition from left to right), so $\langle V\rangle\ge \langle (1,2), (1,2,...,n)\rangle$. Hence $\langle V\rangle=S_n$.

For the second part you need to prove that $(i,i+1)$ is not a product of other transpositions from $V$. That is because the sets $A=\{1,...,i\}, B=\{i+1,...,n\}$ are invariant under the other transpositions from $V$ (hence under their products), but not invariant under $(i,i+1)$.

Comment: So in the first part, it shows that $V$ generates $W=$ $\{(12),(1...n)\}$, which is known to generate $S_n$. So, it shows $V$ generates $S_n$ too. 
Then, in the second part, to show $V$ is a minimal generating set of $S_n$, I show that by splitting into $V_1$ and $V_2$ , the sets are not invariant under $(i,i+1)$? 
Sorry for the questions, I just want to make sure I'm understanding it

Comment: Yes, for the first part. For the second part, if a set $A$ is invariant for every permutation from a set of permutations $X$. Then $A$ is invariant for every permutation in the subgroup generated by $X$. Since $\{1,2,...,i\}$ is not invariant under $(i,i+1)$ but is invariant under every other permutation in $V$, other permutations in $V$ do not generate $(i,i+1)$.

Comment: When you say invariant, what does it mean? We haven't used "invariant" in class, so I was thinking that maybe we used something equivalent to what you mean by invariant

Comment: $A$ is invariant under $\sigma$ if for every $a\in A$, $\sigma(a)\in A$.

Comment: Makes sense! We used the $σ(a)∈A$ stuff but didn't directly call it invariant, so thanks so much for clearing it up!

Comment: For infinite $A$ you also need $\sigma^{-1}(a)\in A$, but in your case $A$ is finite.