# Show subgroup isomorphic to direct product

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing, permutations, group-isomorphism, direct-product

$T$ is a minimal generating set for $S_n$. $T=${$(i,i+1),i=1,...,n−1$}.

For any fixed $x$ with $1≤x<n$, the set $W =$ $T$\ {$x,x+1 $} does not generate $S_n$.

$W$ generates some subgroup of $S_n$. I want to show that this subgroup is isomorphic to $S_x×S_{n-x}$.

First I let this subgroup be called $G$. So I need to show $G≅S_x×S_{n-x}$.

$W$ doesn't generate $S_n$ when we take out {$x,x+1$}. There's a partition $T_1$, $T_2$, where $T_1=${$1,....,x$},$T_2=$ {$x+1,....,n$}.

Is $S_x$ the $T_1$ and $S_{n-x}$ the $T_2$? And $S_x×S_{n-x}$ is the direct product where the operation is the permutation composition.

Now I need to show $G≅S_x×S_{n-x}$, so do I need to give an isomorphism to prove they are isomorphic, or is there something else I can do to prove it, maybe something about their order?

Comment: This question was posted and answered more than $40$ days ago. You can either accept the answer, or post your own or say what else do you want. The question is listed as having no good answer.

Comment: @markvs sorry about that, i forgot to accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T$ generates $S_n$ for every $n$. Hence $\{(1,2),...,(x-1,x)\}$ generates $S_{T_1}$ and $\{(x+1,x+2),...,(n-1,n)\}$ generates $S_{T_2}$. Let $G$ be the subgroup generated by $W\setminus \{(x,x+1)\}$. Then $T_1, T_2$ are invariant under the action of  $G$. Hence every $g\in G$ induces a permutation $g_1$ of $S_{T_1}$ and a permutation $g_2\in S_{T_2}$. This gives an isomorphism $g\mapsto (g_1, g_2)$ from $G$ to $S_{T_1} \times S_{T_2}$.

Comment: If you have questions about this answer, see my answer to your previous question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4389668/show-least-generating-set-of-s-n/4389678#4389678

Comment: $S_{T_1}$ is just $S_x$ and $S_{T_2}$ is $S_{n-x}$ right?

Comment: Yes, $S_{T_1}$, the group of permutations of $T_1$, is isomorphic to $S_x$ and $S_{T_2}$ is isomorphic to $S_{n-x}$.

Comment: okay, so the group of permutations $S_{T_1}$, and $S_{T_2}$ are isomorphic to $S_x$ and $S_{n-x}$. So every element of $G$ will have a permutation in $S_{T_1}$ and in $S_{T_2}$ So the elements of $G$ will be isomorphisms from $G$ to $S_{x} × S_{n-x}$ through their permutations in $S_{T_1}$ and $S_{T_2}$....am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: For every element $g$, its restriction to $T_1$ is a permutation $g_1$ from $S_{T_1}$ and its restriction on $T_2$ is a permutation $g_2$ from $S_{T_2}$. The map $g\mapsto (g_1,g_2)$ is a homomorphism from $G$ to $S_{T_1} \times S_{T_2}$, which is surjective and injective, hence isomorphism.

Comment: Oh okay, makes sense!! Thanks for the help!!